# Control two servos from WinForms C# application with Arduino Uno

Tags: c#, arduino, arduino-uno, servo

I'm trying to figure out, how to control two servos separately from `WinForms` `C#` desktop application.

In `C#` initialization:

```
 myport.PortName = "COM6";
 myport.BaudRate = 9600;
 myport.Open();
```

Controlled by `trackBar1`:

```
private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (myport.IsOpen)
     {
         myport.WriteLine(trackBar1.Value.ToString());
     }
}
```

Arduino code  moves servos with `pin 9` and `11`, one goes to left, anther to right side synchronously :

```
#include <Servo.h>
Servo servo1;
Servo servo2;
int val;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    servo1.attach(9);
    servo2.attach(11);
}

void loop() {
  val = Serial.parseInt();
  if(val != 0){
    servo1.write(val);
    servo2.write(val);
  }
}
```

to control direction, I can create separate function void for `servo1` and `servo2` with different angle value, but  I can't figure out, how to get separate control for each servo from `C#` application. I'm not sure, what I have to add in `Arduino uploaded code` and `C#`, for example, if I want control `servo2` from `pin 11` with `trackBar2` and `servo1` from `pin 9` with `trackBar1`:

```
private void trackBar2_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (myport.IsOpen)
    {
        myport.WriteLine(trackBar2.Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Any advice, guide or example would be very helpful

Comment: one option would be, instead of just reading ints on your Arduino, wait for character 'A' or 'B', then read an int. If the character is 'A' move servo1, if the character is 'B' move servo2. In your .net app, Write 'A' or 'B' before sending the trackbar value.

Comment: Now that you want to send more than one value, you should design a protocol. For example you could always send all servo-values or you could send a servo-id and value. Mind if you are planning on doing even more later, you might want to make your protocol be extensible accordingly.

Comment: @ikkentim Hello, I'm new with Arduino and controllers at all, I'm not sure how to do it, can you provide any guide of example, where I have to send this variables A and B from C# and get it in uploaded code?

Comment: @Fildor Hello,  I'm really new with Arduino, can you provide any guide of example how to design protocol to send servo-values or servo-id from C# and get it in uploaded code?

Comment: I found this for a start. https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/4214/communication-protocol-best-practices-and-patterns Searching Arduino SE may be a good idea anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be, instead of just reading ints on your Arduino, wait for character 'A' or 'B', then read an int. If the character is 'A' move servo1, if the character is 'B' move servo2. In your .net app, Write 'A' or 'B' before sending the trackbar value

Note: Untested

```
// in Arduino
void loop() {
  switch(Serial.read())
  {
    case 'A':
      servo1.write(Serial.parseInt());
      break;
    case 'B':
      servo2.write(Serial.parseInt());
      break;
  }
}


// in c#
myport.Write('B')
myport.WriteLine(trackBar2.Value.ToString());
```

Comment: Thank you, very useful answer